# How to solve ' Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK' on table 'Table' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem with migrations in EF Core 5.0 :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Trades_Signals_SignalID' on
> table 'Trades' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON
> DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
> constraints.

Here is the tables:

```
public class Signal
{
    public int SignalID { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public int Buy { get; set; }
    public int Sell { get; set; }
    public int Neutral { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CoinID { get; set; }
    public virtual Coin Coin { get; set; }
    public int? TradeID { get; set; }
    public Trade Trade { get; set; }
}

public class Trade
{
    public int TradeID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CoinID { get; set; }

    public virtual Coin Coin { get; set; }
    public DateTime TradeDate { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(16,8)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(16,8)")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public TradeStatus Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Signal")]
    public int? SignalID { get; set; }
    public virtual Signal Signal { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8,2)")]
    public decimal ProfitLoss { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried lots of things, but continue to get errors.

I tried this with the same error:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Trade>().HasOne<Signal>(s => s.Signal).WithOne(t => t.Trade).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: It seems you intended to put `Signal` and `Trade` in a one-to-one relationship. If so, then you have to decide which of them you want to be the principal end and which one the dependent end. Simply put, between `Signal` and `Trade` which one depends on the other one?

Comment: Also, share the `Coin` model.